Do not hide ContextMenu when option selected
In my context Menu I have some checkable options.
Is there a way to inhibite Context Menu hide when one checkable option was selected?

A ContextMenu is meant to close automatically when you select an option. If you want to keep it open after an item is clicked, you'll need to use a custom approach, such as a custom dialog or a BottomSheet.
